# Is there a way to use MAX() with automated multiple range values?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need the range values to go from `A:A, B:B, ..., [Current Column]`. it needs to be dynamic for multiple columns, i.e Column D be `=MAX(A:A, B:B, C:C)`, while Column E will be `=MAX(A:A, B:B, C:C, D:D)`.

`=MAX(COUNTIF(A:A, “*Text*”), COUNTIF(B:B, “*[Text String]*”), ..., [until current COLUMN() - 1])`

Or something like

```
=MAX( 
 Loop ( COLUMN() - 1 )
 {
  COUNTIF( 
   INDIRECT(
    ADDRESS(3, [Loop Iteration]) & ":" & ADDRESS([Dynamic Number], [Loop Iteration])
   )
  , “*[Text String]*” )
 }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

dragging solution:

```
=MAX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3, 1)&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(A3:A), COLUMN()-1)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

non-dragging automated solution:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(COLUMN(A:E)&"×"&IFNA(HLOOKUP(
 IF(FLATTEN(COLUMN(A:E)-1)>=COLUMN(A:E),,COLUMN(A:E)-(FLATTEN(COLUMN(A:E))-1)), 
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(A3:E="",, COLUMN(A:E)&"×"&A3:E)), "×"), 
 "select max(Col2) pivot Col1")*1, 2, 0))), "×"), 
 "select max(Col2) pivot Col1"), "offset 1", 0))
```

[image]